# Problem installing iCloud Drive app in iOS 11

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, icloud

If I try to download the [iCloud Drive](https://itunes.apple.com/app/icloud-drive/id1070072560) app on my iPhone 6 and iPad Pro running iOS 11, I get the following message on the app download screen:

*This app requires specific features not available on this device*.

[image]

[image]

Both the devices are running iOS 11.4.1 (latest version as of this writing). What specific features are missing from this devices restricting me from installing the app?

Comment: Doubt this is the issue, but have you logged into iCloud?

Comment: I just logged on from my iMac and all seemed fine. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

<strike>This keep happening with some users over the time. Most likely some issues at the Apple's servers end.</strike>

In case this issue is reported when you are fully confident that your device has the capability to run the said app, the most likely explanation is a temporary glitch from Apple's end.

The recommended approach here is to wait for some time and try again.

The [iCloud Drive](https://itunes.apple.com/app/icloud-drive/id1070072560) app in iOS 11 and later is superseded  by a new app called [Files](https://itunes.apple.com/app/files/id1232058109) by Apple.

Files app support connecting to multiple storage sources with iCloud Drive connected by default.

iCloud Drive app is still available on the App Store for older devices running iOS 10. Files app is only available for iOS 11 and later.

Since both the (similar) apps need to remain available on the App Store for supporting iOS 10 and 11, this approach has been taken where the Files app is supported only on devices running iOS 11 and later, while iCloud Drive app is restricted from getting installed on iOS 11.

Comment: Thanks for your input. I waited all night but I get the same message.  Any other suggestions?

Comment: @jmh I just checked the app on the App Store and I am getting a similar message displayed. The app description says that it is supported on devices running iOS 10 and later. It appears that it is no longer updated/maintained by Apple. [Files app](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/files/id1232058109?mt=8) by Apples looks like a replace for the iCloud Drive app.

Comment: Interesting.  I have the Files app and noticed it is not an apple product so this surprises me.  Thank you.

Comment: @jmh Files app is Apples own app and is preinstalled in iOS. If that works for you, i'll update the answer.

Comment: @jmh My hunch is that since Files app is available only for devices running iOS 11 and later, iCloud Drive app is left on app store only for older devices and it is disabled for iOS 11 devices as the two apps offer similar functionality.

Comment: I'm not being stubborn but there seems to be a big difference in what iCloud did and what the Files app does. Maybe I'm missing something here. Thanks.

Comment: I think you probably just haven’t seen the right section in the app or something — I’m not aware of any functionality that Apple removed when they made Files. It can now show files from other sources, like Dropbox, but by default it’s set up with iCloud Drive as the only source. Is there anything specific you think it’s missing?

Comment: Yes, icloud synchs with all your ios devices as well as your Mac.  It also offers a large amount of storage you can use in conjunction with your internal drives.  There is no Files app for macos.